# XML Deserialization Not Setting Class Values

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-3.5, xml-deserialization

I am not seeing what I am doing wrong. To see what was being done, I changed the constructor values to "TEST", after the XML gets read in (I verified what the XML is), the class values are still stuck to "TEST". Any more Ideas? I am doing this process already in another class that works fine, neither me nor some co-workers could find the difference.

XML:

```
<IntervalTranslatorScrubberSetting>
  <LINEINDICATOR_USAGE>USG</LINEINDICATOR_USAGE>
  <FILETYPE>867</FILETYPE>
  <ESIDUNS>8417397824</ESIDUNS>
</IntervalTranslatorScrubberSetting>
```

CLASS: (Tried without the XMLElement, and tried using XMLAttribute just to see, no change)

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Namespace Workers.Scrubber
    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class IntervalTranslatorScrubberSetting

#Region "Private Variables"
        Private _ESIDuns As String
        Private _FileType As String
        Private _LineIndicator_Usage As String
#End Region

#Region "Constructors"
        Sub New()
            Me.ESIDuns = "TEST"
            Me.FileType = "TEST"
            Me.LineIndicator_Usage = "TEST"
        End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Serialization"
        Private _SerializMe As New XML(Of IntervalTranslatorScrubberSetting)

        Public Function Serialize(ByVal XMLObject As IntervalTranslatorScrubberSetting) As String
            Return _SerializMe.Serialize(XMLObject)
        End Function

        Public Function Deserialize(ByVal XML As String) As IntervalTranslatorScrubberSetting
            Return _SerializMe.Deserialize(XML)
        End Function
#End Region

#Region "Properties"
        <XmlElement()> _
        Public Property ESIDuns() As String
            Get
                Return _ESIDuns
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ESIDuns = value
            End Set
        End Property

        <XmlElement()> _
        Public Property FileType() As String
            Get
                Return _FileType
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _FileType = value
            End Set
        End Property

        <XmlElement()> _
        Public Property LineIndicator_Usage() As String
            Get
                Return _LineIndicator_Usage
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _LineIndicator_Usage = value
            End Set
        End Property
#End Region
    End Class
End Namespace
```

XML Handling Class:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml

Public Class XML(Of T)
    Private _serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(T))

    Public Function Serialize(ByVal myobject As T) As String
        'serialise to a memory stream, then read into a string
        Try
            Dim result As String = Nothing
            If myobject IsNot Nothing Then
                Using ms As New MemoryStream
                    Using xtw As New XmlTextWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                        xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                        _serializer.Serialize(xtw, myobject)
                        'rewind
                        ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
                        Using reader As New StreamReader(ms, Text.Encoding.UTF8)
                            result = reader.ReadToEnd()
                            xtw.Close()
                            reader.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If
            Return result

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Deserialize(ByVal xml As String) As T
        Try
            'default to no object
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(xml) Then
                Using sr As New StringReader(xml)
                    Return CType(_serializer.Deserialize(sr), T)
                End Using
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Can't immediately see the problem.  The XML you've provided looks like it wasn't generated by this code -- would it be helpful to compare it with the XML generated by serialising this class?

Comment: Not a bad idea, not sure why I did not think of that. Let met me try and see what that does.

Comment: This is nothing to do with the question, but you don't need the `<Serializable()>` attribute for `System.Xml.Serialization`

Comment: @MarkJ, Thanks, I know, it was there originally, then added the reference when I was trying the other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay using @maxc 's suggestion, I tried the serialization of the class, and saw nothing different except for the capitalization of my XML attributes vs. my properties. I did not think this stuff was case sensitive? But when I changed it so their cases matched, it works, even changed it back and forth to confirm.

Weird?

Comment: Not weird at all, Xml is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes XML is, but VB.Net is not, wish it was. The "is it or is it not" for the VB.Net libraries is getting old.